# How to update StreamBuilder after removeAt

Tags: flutter, list, stream-builder

I have a parent widget **DocumentPicker** with a child **DocumentCard**.

I'm trying to update the `StreamBuilder` inside DocumentPicker when I click on the delete IconButton inside DocumentCard.

Actually I have a **FileListController** and inside it `StreamController<List?>`, `Sink<List?>`, `Stream<List?>` used for update StreamBuilder when an object is added.

Now I'm trying to use Stream<List?> to update the StreamBuilder when an item is removed.
For that I've tried to use `StreamSubscription<List?>` inside an `initState()` in DocumentCard:

I've done this:

FileListController:

```
import 'dart:async';

import '../model/document.dart';

class FileListController {
  final StreamController<List<Document>?> controller = StreamController<List<Document>?>.broadcast();

  Sink<List<Document>?> get inputFileList => controller.sink;
  Stream<List<Document>?> get outputFileList => controller.stream;
}
```

DocumentPicker:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_test/provider/document_view_model.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

import '../constant/color.dart';
import '../constant/text.dart';
import '../model/document.dart';
import '../utils/file_list_controller.dart';
import 'document_card.dart';

class DocumentPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const DocumentPicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DocumentPicker> createState() => _DocumentPickerState();
}

class _DocumentPickerState extends State<DocumentPicker> {
  final photoTitleController = TextEditingController();
  File? _file;
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  List<Document>? documents = [];
  late Document document;
  String extension = "";
  String destination = "";
  final FileListController fileController = FileListController();

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Free memory allocated to the existing variables ----------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  @override
  void dispose() {
    photoTitleController.dispose();
    fileController.controller.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String fileName = _file != null ? Path.basename(_file!.path) : noFileSelectedText;

    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            //----------------------------- Pick file from device --------------
            TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                _clickOnAddFile();
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.download,
                size: 30,
                color: googleButtonTextColor,
              ),
              label: const Text(
                addFile,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: googleButtonTextColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //----------------------------- Validate picked file ---------------
            TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _clickOnValidate();
                _clearPhotoTitleTextField();
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.done,
                size: 30,
                color: googleButtonTextColor,
              ),
              label: const Text(
                validate,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: googleButtonTextColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        //----------------------------- Picked file default name ---------------
        Text(
          fileName,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: black,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10,),
        //----------------------------- Picked file title ----------------------
        TextField(
          controller: photoTitleController,
          cursorColor: cursorColor,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: const Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              color: grey,
              size: 30,
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.5),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.orange),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.5),
            ),
            labelText: fileTitleText,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10,),
        //----------------------------- Show list of picked file ---------------
        StreamBuilder<List<Document>?>(
            stream: fileController.outputFileList,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasData) {
                print("List sent to doc card: ${snapshot.data!}");
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => DocumentCard(
                    document: snapshot.data![index],
                    extension: extension,
                    documents: snapshot.data!,
                    index: index,
                  ),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                );
              }
              else {
                return const SizedBox(height: 0,);
              }
            },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Pick file from device ------------------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Future _clickOnAddFile() async{
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        allowMultiple: false,
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "pdf"],
    );

    if(result == null) return null;

    final path = result.files.single.path!;
    extension = result.files.first.extension!;

    setState(() => _file = File(path));
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Validate picked file -------------------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Future _clickOnValidate() async {
    if(_file == null) return null;

    final defaultName = Path.basename(_file!.path);
    final fileName = photoTitleController.text.trim();
    destination = "instructorDocuments/${user!.uid}/$fileName";

    if(fileName.isEmpty) {
      destination = "instructorDocuments/${user!.uid}/$defaultName";
    }

    document = Document(_file, fileName);
    documents?.add(document);
    fileController.inputFileList.add(documents);

    if (documents != null) {
      for(var d in documents!){
        DocumentViewModel.uploadInstructorDocument(destination, d.documentPhoto!);
      }
    }
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Clear photo title text field -----------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  _clearPhotoTitleTextField() {
    photoTitleController.clear();
  }
}
```

DocumentCard:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_test/model/document.dart';

import '../constant/color.dart';
import '../constant/text.dart';
import '../utils/file_list_controller.dart';

class DocumentCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Document document;
  final String extension;
  final List<Document>? documents;
  final int index;

  const DocumentCard({Key? key, required this.document,
    required this.extension, required this.documents, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DocumentCard> createState() => _DocumentCardState();
}

class _DocumentCardState extends State<DocumentCard> {
  final FileListController fileController = FileListController();
  late StreamSubscription<List<Document>?> subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    subscription = fileController.controller.stream.listen((event) {
      event!.removeAt(widget.index);
      print("List after remove inside InitState: ${event.length}");
    },
    );
    super.initState();
  }
  
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Free memory allocated to the existing variables ----------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  @override
  void dispose() {
    fileController.controller.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Document: ${widget.documents} \n"
          "Index item: ${widget.index}");

    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          //----------------------------- Picked file image --------------------
          Image.file(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            widget.document.documentPhoto!,
            errorBuilder: (context, exception, stackTrace) {
              return widget.extension == "pdf" || widget.extension != "jpg" || widget.extension != "jpeg" || widget.extension != "png"
                  ? Image.asset(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    "assets/images/pdf.png",
                  )
                  : Container(
                      color: grey,
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                            errorLoadImage,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                  );
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20,),
          //----------------------------- Picked file title --------------------
          Text(
            widget.document.photoTitle!,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: black,
            ),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          //----------------------------- Delete icon button -------------------
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("List size before delete: ${widget.documents!.length}");
                _deleteDocument(widget.index);
                print("List size after delete: ${widget.documents!.length}");
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.delete,
                color: red,
              ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Delete document ------------------------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Future _deleteDocument(int index) async {
    widget.documents!.removeAt(index);
    //fileController.inputFileList.add(widget.documents!);
  }
}
```

**Edit: I've tried this with no result**

DocumentCard:

```
class DocumentCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Document document;
  final String extension;
  final void Function()? deleteDocument; <--------------------------------------

  const DocumentCard({Key? key, required this.document,
    required this.extension, required this.deleteDocument}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
}
```

onPressed dans DocumentCard:

```
IconButton(
    onPressed: () {
      deleteDocument; <--------------------------------------
      print("Delete icon clicked");
    },
    icon: const Icon(
             Icons.delete,
             color: red,
          )
),
```

DocumentPicker:

```
deletePickedFile(Document document) {
    documents!.remove(document);
}
```

StreamBuilder in DocumentPicker:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Document>?>(
            stream: fileController.outputFileList,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => DocumentCard(
                    document: snapshot.data![index],
                    extension: extension,
                    deleteDocument: deletePickedFile(snapshot.data![index]), <----------
                  ),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                );
              }
              else {
                return const SizedBox(height: 0,);
              }
            },
        ),
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have data that might need mutating inside a Stream?  Just make a List somewhere.

Comment: @Randal Schwartz
Because the data comes from a FilePicker